# How to count checkboxes for a given date and paste it as number in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to develop a task management system where I need to check all the completed tasks for a given date.

Pls refer to the attached [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RSwuQRTNpXityXa2KQ2J1XFGeUWpfdVr-znZZSLf1ns/edit?usp=sharing).

When I check the box as complete (Column B), Column C automatically has to print the current date. For that I gave the equation: =if(B3=True,NOW(),"")

Each time a checkbox is checked, the date will be automatically added in column C.

But the real challenge is I also want to display the number of tasks I completed on a specific date in Column F. For that, I gave the equation: =COUNTIFs(B:B=true,C:C=E4)

But as you can see, the answer comes in zero. I even checked if the two dates are equal by checking: =if(E4=C4,True,False), and the answer came out False.

Although both the dates are equal, how come they are false? How can I solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few changes, that you should do:-

1. Use `TODAY()` instead of `NOW()` in your case, as `NOW` returns `Time` also, which is the making it showing `false`, so change this `=if(B3=True,NOW(),"")` to `=if(B3=True,TODAY(),"")`.
2. You're wrongly using `COUNTIFS`, so change this `=COUNTIFs(B:B=true,C:C=E4)` to `=COUNTIFS(B:B,true,C:C,E4)`

**Reference:-**

[NOW()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en)

[TODAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en)

[COUNTIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)